# replacing appointed characters in a string in txt file

Tags: python

Hello all…I want to pick up the texts ‘DesingerXXX’ from a text file which contains below contents:

```
C  DesignerTEE edBore 1 1/42006
Cylinder SingleVerticalB DesignerHHJ e 1 1/8Cooling 1
EngineBore 11/16 DesignerTDT 8Length 3Width 3
EngineCy DesignerHEE Inline2008Bore 1
Height 4TheChallen DesignerTET e 1Stroke 1P 305
Height 8C 606Wall15ccG DesignerQBG ccGasEngineJ 142
Height DesignerEQE C 60150ccGas2007
```

Anidea is to use the ‘Designer’ as a key, to consider each line into 2 parts, before the key, and after the key.

```
file_object = open('C:\\file.txt')
lines = file_object.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if 'Designer' in line:
        where = line.find('Designer')
        before = line[0:where]
        after = line[where:len(line)]

file_object.close()
```

In the ‘before the key’ part, I need to find the LAST space (‘ ’), and replace to another symbol/character.

In the ‘after the key’ part, I need to find the FIRST space (‘ ’), and replace to another symbol/character.

Then, I can slice it and pick up the wanted according to the new symbols/characters.

**is there a better way to pick up the wanted texts? Or not, how can I replace the appointed key spaces?**

In the string replace function, I can limit the times of replacing but not exactly which I can replace. How can I do that?

thanks

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: Why not simply [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions, its a trivial task:

```
>>> s = '''C  DesignerTEE edBore 1 1/42006
... Cylinder SingleVerticalB DesignerHHJ e 1 1/8Cooling 1
... EngineBore 11/16 DesignerTDT 8Length 3Width 3
... EngineCy DesignerHEE Inline2008Bore 1
... Height 4TheChallen DesignerTET e 1Stroke 1P 305
... Height 8C 606Wall15ccG DesignerQBG ccGasEngineJ 142
... Height DesignerEQE C 60150ccGas2007'''
>>> import re
>>> exp = 'Designer[A-Z]{3}'
>>> re.findall(exp, s)
['DesignerTEE', 'DesignerHHJ', 'DesignerTDT', 'DesignerHEE', 'DesignerTET', 'DesignerQBG', 'DesignerEQE']
```

The regular expression is `Designer[A-Z]{3}` which means the letters `Designer`, followed by any letter from capital `A` to capital `Z` that appears 3 times, and only three times.

So, it won't match `DesignerABCD` (4 letters), it also wont match `Desginer123` (123 is not valid letters).

It also won't match `Designerabc` (abc are small letters). To make it ignore the case, you can pass an optional flag `re.I` as a third argument; but this will also match `designerabc` (you have to be very specific with regular expressions).

So, to make it so that it matches `Designer` followed by exactly 3 upper or lower case letters, you'd have to change the expression to `Designer[Aa-zZ]{3}`.

If you want to search and replace, then you can use `re.sub` for substituting matches; so if I want to replace all matches with the word 'hello':

```
>>> x = re.sub(exp, 'hello', s)
>>> print(x)
C  hello edBore 1 1/42006
Cylinder SingleVerticalB hello e 1 1/8Cooling 1
EngineBore 11/16 hello 8Length 3Width 3
EngineCy hello Inline2008Bore 1
Height 4TheChallen hello e 1Stroke 1P 305
Height 8C 606Wall15ccG hello ccGasEngineJ 142
Height hello C 60150ccGas2007
```

---

> and what if both before and after 'Designer', there are characters,
>   and the length of character is not fixed. I tried
>   '[Aa-zZ]Designer[Aa-zZ]{0~9}', but it doesn't work..

For these things, there are special characters in regular expressions. Briefly summarized below:

- When you want to say "1 or more, but at least 1", use `+`
- When you want to say "0 or any number, but there maybe none", use `*`
- When you want to say "none but if it exists, only repeats once" use `?`

You use this after the expression you want to be modified with the "repetition" modifiers.

For more on this, have a read through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Now your requirements is *"there **are characters** but **the length is not fixed**"*, based on this, we have to use `+`.

Comment: thanks, Mr. Khalid. this is amazing! and what if both before and after 'Designer', there are characters, and the length of character is not fixed. I tried '[Aa-zZ]Designer[Aa-zZ]{0~9}', but it doesn't work..

Comment: @Burhan Khalid `[Aa-zZ]` matches A, any lower case letter, or Z, it doesn't match letters in the range B-Y. To match any upper or lower case letter you need `[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `re.sub`. The regular expression match with your keyword surrounded by spaces. The second parameter of sub, replace the surrounder spaces by your_special_char (in my script a hyphen)

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('file.txt') as file_object:
...     your_special_char = '-'
...     for line in file_object:
...         formated_line = re.sub(r'(\s)(Designer[A-Z]{3})(\s)', r'%s\2%s' % (your_special_char,your_special_char), line)
...         print formated_line
... 
C -DesignerTEE-edBore 1 1/42006
Cylinder SingleVerticalB-DesignerHHJ-e 1 1/8Cooling 1
EngineBore 11/16-DesignerTDT-8Length 3Width 3
EngineCy-DesignerHEE-Inline2008Bore 1
Height 4TheChallen-DesignerTET-e 1Stroke 1P 305
Height 8C 606Wall15ccG-DesignerQBG-ccGasEngineJ 142
Height-DesignerEQE-C 60150ccGas2007
```

Comment: hi, xecgr. glad to see you again. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maroun Maroun mentioned 'Why not simply split the string'. so guessing one of the working way is:

```
import re

file_object = open('C:\\file.txt')
lines = file_object.readlines()

b = []

for line in lines:
    a = line.split()
    for aa in a:
        b.append(aa)

for bb in b:
    if 'Designer' in bb:
        print bb

file_object.close()
```